# TVML tv-placeholder with custom size image

Tags: css, tvos, tvml

I'm very new to TVML and web development. I'm trying to use the **tv-placeholder**  style **tv** to set a default image for an **img**

It works when I use the size configuration:

```
width: 520; height: 280;
```

However, It does not with the custom size

```
width: 1235; height: 314
```

Comment: Try keeping the ratio consistent. For example `width: 1235; height: 665;` P.S Are you sure these numbers don't need a unit defined? like `px`?

Comment: Thank you Aziz. Keeping the ratio consistent works. My issue is that I have a custom size for the image (width: 1235; height: 314) and I want to add the placeholder to it.

Comment: then just add whitespace around your image? As in place in the middle of a larger document with the extra space empty

Answer (score 0):

I can advice you to implement your own TVML-item that will be used as an image with a custom placeholder (also, you will be able to implement cache policy). Read more about the `TVMLKit`. I think you will need to inherit `TVImageElement` class and override some methods. You will be able to use any images with any resolutions from any sources (local storage and other).